# grep - replacing a set of different numbers with the same set of numbers

Tags: linux, grep

I am a novice with grep, and am wondering how I could go about doing the following: I have a file with ~1000 lines that are in this format

```
assign ( resid 105 and name CB ) ( resid 105 and name CA ) 4.1 0.8 0.8

assign ( resid 44 and name CB ) ( resid 44 and name CA ) 4.4 0.9 0.9
```

I want to change the numbers at the end to the following:

```
4.6 2.6 2.6 !
```

Is there any way I can go about doing this? The numbers in each line are different and I am trying to make them all consistent and add "!" at the end of each line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is for printing matching and printing data from a file. To replace data, there is `sed`:

```
sed 's|[0-9]\..*$|4.6 2.6 2.6 !|g' file
```

That replaces all of the numbers at the very end of each line with `4.6 2.6 2.6 !` no matter what they are or how many there are.

To edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's|[0-9]\..*$|4.6 2.6 2.6 !|g' file
```

Output:

```
assign ( resid 105 and name CB ) ( resid 105 and name CA ) 4.6 2.6 2.6 !

assign ( resid 44 and name CB ) ( resid 44 and name CA ) 4.6 2.6 2.6 !
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, this time using `awk` to do the text processing:

```
awk '{gsub(/([[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]] ?){3}$/,"4.6 2.6 2.6 !")}1' file
```

This (also) replaces a pattern of three times "digit" "`.`" "digit" (and possibly space) at the end of the line with the string you specified.

Output (again)

```
assign ( resid 105 and name CB ) ( resid 105 and name CA ) 4.6 2.6 2.6 !

assign ( resid 44 and name CB ) ( resid 44 and name CA ) 4.6 2.6 2.6 !
```

Note that the syntax used is not completely portable; `mawk` e.g. doesn't understand the `{number}` construct for repetition count, so you may have to resort to

```
awk '{gsub(/[0-9]\.[0-9] [0-9]\.[0-9] [0-9]\.[0-9]$/,"4.6 2.6 2.6 !")}1' file
```

if you are using such an implementation of `awk`.